# howto make a list in haskell selectable to the user in the console output?

Tags: list, haskell

hi i have a problem, i have a list of items, for a simple understanding i have a `[String]` list

now there are several items, but not all items should be in there, so i need to do some things:

1. print the list to the user in the console (easy with `map putStrLn list`)
2. i need to let the user select items which should be used/deleted, how to do this?
3. then i can work on the selected items and use/delete it

i need help to do the selection. i can't use a GUI and have only the console.

have somebody a idea?

Comment: Are you asking how to design a user interface?  Just number the strings, print them, and let the user pick a number.

Comment: This question is far too open-ended and ambiguous to be worthwhile. You need to get input from the user using something like `getLine`, process the input and list of data, then repeat as needed. Most of this is not difficult, but it's impossible to help without knowing what you've already done and having a more specific question about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You need a more detailed specification of the problem you're solving. For instance in the interface, should the user remove an element one by one or just write many indices at one line? Questions like this should be unambiguous before starting to code (for any language!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, I'd suggest to use the module `Text.Printf` for formatting. We also need `Data.Functor` for `<$>`:

```
import Text.Printf (printf)
import Data.Functor ((<$>))
```

Print out the list and some indices:

```
putList = mapM (printf "%2d: %s\n") . zipWith [1..]
```

Print a prompt:

```
prompt = putStr "Enter a whitespace-separated list of entries to delete.\n> "
```

Read in the indices:

```
readIndices = map read . words <$> getLine
```

get a filtered list:

```
filtered ix = map snd . filter (flip notElem ix . fst) . zipWith [1..]
```

And put the blocks together:

```
filterList ls = do putList ls
                   prompt
                   ix <- readIndices
                   return $! filtered ix ls
```

That's all! If you have any further question, please ask.